# How do I run a socket.io as continuosly service without sleep or pause on android?

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, socket.io, android-service

I developing a chat app.I create a background service for connection of socket.io.But when send a message,server disconnected.I need Socket.io Connection always work in background service.How can I do that?
its my background service:

```
public class BackService extends Service {
    SocketIO socket;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();




    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            socket = new SocketIO("http://192.168.9.43:8001/");

        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
            }

            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                System.out.println("an Error occured");
                socketIOException.printStackTrace();
            }

            public void onDisconnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
            }

            public void onConnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection established");
            }

            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yeni mesaj var", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("yeni mesaj var");
            }
        });

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }




        return START_STICKY;

    }

}
```

And its my screenchat for chat:

```
    public class ScreenChat extends Activity {
    EditText mEditMessage;
    Button mBtnSend;
    ListView mListMessage;

    public static final String TAG = "socketIO";
    boolean isConnected;
    public static final String KEY_DEVICE_ID = "sender";
    public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
    public String device_id;
    SocketIOClient mClient;
    MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
    String userName;
    ArrayList<Message> mMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_chat);
        device_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            userName = extras.getString("UserName");
        }
        mBtnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        mEditMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_message);
        mListMessage = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_message);
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, mMessages);
        mListMessage.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
        mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mBtnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mClient == null)
                    return;
                Message message = new Message();
                message.setMessage(mEditMessage.getText().toString());
                message.setSender(userName);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(message);
                if (mClient.isConnected()) {
                    mClient.emit(json);
                    mEditMessage.getText().clear();
                    mMessages.add(message);
                    mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        SocketIOClient.connect(AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance(),
                "http://192.168.9.43:8001/", mConnectCallback);
    }

    public void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
        mListMessage.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mListMessage.setSelection(mMessageAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
    }

    ConnectCallback mConnectCallback = new ConnectCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConnectCompleted(Exception ex, SocketIOClient client) {
            if (ex != null) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            client.setStringCallback(new StringCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onString(String string, Acknowledge acknowledge) {
                    Log.d("SOCKET", string);
                }
            });

            client.setJSONCallback(new JSONCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onJSON(JSONObject jsonObject,
                        Acknowledge acknowledge) {
                    Log.d("SOCKET", jsonObject.toString());
                }
            });

            client.on("event", new EventCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(JSONArray jsonArray, Acknowledge acknowledge) {
                    Log.d("SOCKET", jsonArray.toString());
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Message>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    ArrayList<Message> messages = gson.fromJson(
                            jsonArray.toString(), listType);
                    mMessages.addAll(messages);
                    scrollMyListViewToBottom();
                }
            });
            mClient = client;
        }
    };
}
```

How can I do work socket.io as a background service continuous running?

Answer (score 0):

You can knock the repeated code in your main activity. You just need to initialize the service in your main activity.

```
    private void startMyService(){
    Intent ServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BackService.class);
    //ServiceIntent.putExtra(USER_DATA, obj.toString()); if you want to provide any info to the service class
    this.startService(ServiceIntent);
    }
```